# Laravel migrate command is not working for remote database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4.2

I am working on a project using the Laravel 4.2 framework. I want to execute the command `php artisan migrate` but when I run this command it shows an error:

> [PDOException]
>       SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 CREATE command denied to user 'abc'@'10.1.1.27' for table 'migrations'

I think I have placed the project files and the database on different servers, so that's why am I getting this error.

Database server: 10.1.1.56

Project server: 10.1.1.27 (localhost)

Comment: post your env file details

Comment: Have no .env file in project

Comment: it maybe hidden..

Comment: are you checking from the ide?

Comment: I am using xampp and want to execute command from cmd but database is on different location(server)

Comment: yeah i got that..but where are you giving the database credentials?

Comment: like database user name database host and all that..

Comment: In app/config/database.php and params are: 'mysql' => array(
 'driver'    => 'mysql',
 'host'      => '10.1.1.56',
 'database'  => 'rnd_test',
 'username'  => 'abc',
 'password'  => 'abc123',
 'charset'   => 'utf8',
 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
 'prefix'    => '',
),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159214/discussion-between-darshan-and-anil).

Comment: @anil Make sure that your configuration is correct.

Comment: this has to do with your laravel database configuration

Comment: yes laravel configuration is correct. when i connect with local database then migrate command is working but when changed to remote database then migrate command generate error

Comment: May I ask what is your mysql version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error indicates that the remote MySQL database isn't configured to allow certain operations executed by the user `abc` from the IP address *10.1.1.27*. In many cases, MySQL users are set up to allow access from the the *same* host as the database server, but we need to explicitly [`GRANT` access](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) for clients connecting to the database from a remote host.

We can use the following commands to grant the user `abc` access from remote hosts. We must run these commands as a user that has the ability to grant privileges to other users (such as the database's *root* user):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'abc'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Replace `database` with the name of the application's database configured in *.env* or *config/database.php*. The wildcard `'%'` in `'username'@'%'` indicates that we want to give permissions to that user from *any* IP address. If we don't want to allow the user access from *any* IP address, we can limit access to specific IP addresses by replacing the wildcard with the address to allow (*10.1.1.27* in this case).

Depending on the needs of the project, we may not need to give a user all privileges to a database. See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) for a list of available privileges that we can assign.

Answer (score 1):

`1142 CREATE command denied to user 'abc'@'10.1.1.27' for table 'migrations'`

The above command simply means that the user don't have `CREATE` permission on the connected database. So first of all you have to grant the privileges to that user on the database and after that run the migration.

**Explanation:** When you run `migrate`, a table is created on with the name `migration` in the database that maintains the status of migration ion it, and you don'r have the `CREATE` permission that's why it is showing error.